# Python pip install xlswriter does not work

Tags: python, pip

I have to install the xlswriter package in python for my project but i've tried with the pip installer and it does not work.

Here's what i typed in the elevated cmd:
`pip install xlswriter`
Here's the error :

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xlswriter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xlswriter
```

I also tried `pip install XlsWriter` but same issue appears

I tried to install other packages to test the pip installer with for example pandas
`pip install pandas` and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no module of that name, see https://pypi.org/search/?q=xlswriter&o= which yields no result

Maybe you meant Xls**x**Writer (https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/ and https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html):

```
pip install XlsxWriter
```